# Markov Chains: Enlarge State Space & Long-time Probability

Tags: markov-chain

I can't figure out how to solve this. I've looked at many examples to help, but nothing seems to.

Let S and C denote a Sunny day and a Cloudy day, respectively. Suppose that the weather on the given day depends on the past weather only through the weather on the two immediately preceding days according to the following conditional probabilities: The probability that a day is sunny given that the immediately preceding two days were sunny is P(S|S,S) = .8. The probability that a day is sunny given that the immediately preceding day was sunny and the day before was cloudy is P(S|C,S) = .6.The probability that a day is sunny given that the immediately preceding day was cloudy and the day before was sunny is P(S|S,C) = .4. Similarly, P(S|C,C) = .1, P=(C|S,S) =.2, P(C|C,S) = .4, P(C|S,C) = .6, P(C|C,C) = .9. Let n = 0 denote the initial day (day 0), let n = 1 denote the 1st day, and so on. We also know the following two initial probabilities: Prob(the initial day is cloudy, the first day is sunny) = .1 and Prob (the initial day is cloudy, the first day is cloudy) = .9.

a.) What is the probability that the second and third day will be cloudy? b.) What is the probability that the third day will be cloudy? c.) What is the long-term probability that a day will be cloudy?

Update
$$
        \begin{matrix}
 &(S,S)& (S,C) &(C,S) & (C,C)\\
   (S,S)&    .8 & .2 & 0 & 0 \\
    (S,C)&     0 & 0 & .4 & .6 \\
    (C,S)&   .6 & .4 & 0 & 0 \\
       (C,C)& 0 & 0 & .1 & .9 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: Hint: The question defines a four-state Markov chain on the states $\{(S,S), (S,C), (C,S), (C,C)\}$.  For instance, "$P(S|C,S)=0.6$" means the chance of a transition from $(C,S)$ to $(S,S)$ is $0.6$.

Comment: I have the transition matrix.
  SS SC CS CC
SS.8 .2  0  0
SC 0  0 .4 .6
CS.6 .4  0  0 
CC 0  0 .1 .9

I'm having problems setting up Prob(R2=C, R3=C). Can I take the summation over j in [C,S] of Prob(R3=C, R2=C, R1=j1, R0=j0). 

By doing this I get .753 for the first answer. Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "R3", "R2", "R1", "R0", "j1", and "j0"?

Comment: R3= third day, R2=second day,..., j1 will be either {C or S} for R1, and j0 will be either {C or S} for R0. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense--but it required you to explain it. Anyway, "$\Pr(R_3=C,R_2=C,R_1=j_1,R_0=j_0)$" would refer to a *two-step* transition. The first step would go from $(j_1,j_0)$ on day $1$ to $(C,j_1)$ on day $2$. The second step would go from $(C,j_1)$ to $(C,C)$ on day $3$. The idea is that one transition still occurs each day, but the *states* record the information from the *past two days,* not just the immediately previous day. Note this means that some transitions cannot occur directly, such as $(C,C)\to (S,S)$. That's why your matrix has eight zeros in it.

Comment: Is finding the stated probability above the right set-up to solve Prob(R2=C, R3=C)?

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar question when i was a student and found this [article](http://www.math.bas.bg/~jeni/markov123.pdf)  helpful both to build a general understanding of Markov processes and as a reference for practical applications of the concept. A method that will should solve the problem you outlined is described on page 3, also consider looking at questions 52-61 in the book to test understanding (answers provided in the appendix).

Comment: This is very helpful. We did not learn the tree method in class, so I found this extremely useful. Thank you!

I just have another question. When I'm looking to find the long-run to be cloudy, I sent my matrix to a high power. The results is [3/11 1/1 1/11 6/11] in each row. Each column is represented by (S,S) (S,c) (C,S) (C,C). Do I consider only the (C,C) result or (C,C) + (S,C) for the longrun being cloudy?

Comment: By sending the matrix to higher powers you will most likely find the long-run probabilities or, at least, a close approximation of them. However, if you want to arrive at the exact distribution, you will have to solve it analytically. Here is how: [steady-state calculation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cP3c2PJ4UHg). If you only consider the (C,C) you will "only" find the long run probability of a cloudy day following a cloudy day, so, taking the probability of a cloudy day following a sunny day (S,C) into account as well will do the trick.